# pgfplots: objects outside axis are clipped

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

When I use pgfplots to draw into a 3D axis, the drawn objects outside the axis are sometimes clipped, although I use `clip=false`. This only happens when I use the TikZ externalization library and I think this is caused by pdflatex cropping the external pdf to the bounding box. For example,

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-1,xmax=1,
        ymin=-1,ymax=1,
        zmin=0,zmax=1,
        clip=false]
        \draw (0,0,0) circle (3);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

results in the following external pdf:
[image]

However, I want the whole circle to be shown. So, the question is whether there is a way to automatically adjust the bounding box to include all drawn objects.

Comment: When I use your code I get something completely different; a tiny circle at the lower left corner, (rel axis cs: 0,0,0).  You might want to update you packages.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, you require compat=1.11 or higher to get the output shown above. I've amended the code in my original post to make this clear.

Comment: The good news is that it has nothing to do with pgfplots.  The bad news is that it appears to be inherent in 3D circles.

Comment: As a quick fix, you can expand the bounding box using \path (0,0,0) circle (3.3);

Answer (score 3):

You can save the axis coordinate system and recreate it.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-1,xmax=1,
        ymin=-1,ymax=1,
        zmin=0,zmax=1,
        clip=false]
        \coordinate (origin) at (axis cs: 0,0,0);
        \coordinate (xunit) at (axis cs: 1,0,0);
        \coordinate (yunit) at (axis cs: 0,1,0);
        \coordinate (zunit) at (axis cs: 0,0,1);
    \end{axis}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(origin)}]
      \pgfsetxvec{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{xunit}{center}}%
        {\pgfpointanchor{origin}{center}}}%
      \pgfsetyvec{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{yunit}{center}}%
        {\pgfpointanchor{origin}{center}}}%
      \pgfsetzvec{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{zunit}{center}}%
        {\pgfpointanchor{origin}{center}}}%

      \draw (0,0,0) circle (3);
    \end{scope}
  \draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Your first code does unfortunately not compile on my system - I get an error complaining about a missing semicolon. I've tried some time but I couldn't figure it out, as I'm not familiar with the syntax.

Comment: The second approach seems to be a promising answer. However, if you make the circle wider (5 for example) it will be clipped in the upper region. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: The bounding box does include the cardinal points, like (0,5,0).  One wonders just how circles are drawn.  Using \addplot3 was much slower.

Comment: In your code, if you want to recreate the very coordinate system from the axis, you have to interchange the arguments in the three calls of `\pgfpointdiff`. If you do this, you will get the same result as in my original post. Unfortunately, it seems that there is a principal problem with the bounding box calculation of 3D circles.